# Exporting CSV with specific data from current worksheet (issues with selecting right data)

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if anyone might be able to help me with this problem;
I have a large table. For all the rows in column F that meet a condition (must have a value of 89), I want to select the corresponding rows in columns A, H, and I. I then want to take these rows and export them as a csv file, and the file must be overwritten if it already exists.
For example, Let's say my table looks like;

```
F    A   B   C   H   I
89   45  4   3   6   2
43   23  4   5   4   2
89   3   6   5   65  7
22   43  6   6   2   4
89   56  9   9   35  2
```

So as there are 3 rows in column F that meets the condition and the corresponding column A, H, and I rows have the values (45, 6, 2), (3, 65, 7) and (56, 35, 2) I want my exported file to look something like this;

```
**A   H   I**
  45  6   2
  3   65  7
  56  35  2
```

I am having issues with 2 things:

1. being able to select only the specific cells for the SAME rows in the three wanted columns. Most of the help I found on the internet work only for choosing 1 specific cell, or entire columns. Given that I don't know which rows in column F will meet the condition, I cannot manually choose the corresponding cells in columns A, H, and I, as I don't know the row numbers.
2. My exported file won't act right; it either cannot overwrite (code1) or it keeps overwriting over and over and opens new workbooks when I run the code (code 2)

I have been trying back and forth for some time, and searched through the internet for anything that might help, but I cannot get it to work. As of now I have 2 different codes, that I've been trying to make work, but neither of them do.
The first code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim TransferExport As Integer
Dim u As Integer  
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim data As String
For i = 2 To 18288
If Sheets("Base").Cells(i, 6).Value = "89" Then
u = Sheets("Base").Cells(i, 1).Value
If Sheets("Base").Cells(i, 6).Value = "89" Then
x = Sheets("Base").Cells(i, 8).Value
If Sheets("Base").Cells(i, 6).Value = "89" Then
y = Sheets("Base").Cells(i, 9).Value
End If
End If
End If

TransferExport = FreeFile
data = data & Sheets("Base").Cells(1, 1) & u & " ; "
data = data & Sheets("Base").Cells(1, 8) & x & " ; "
data = data & Sheets("Base").Cells(1, 9) & y & " ; "
Open "C:\Users\bruger1\Documents\Uni\TransferExport.csv" For Append As 
#TransferExport
    Print #TransferExport, u, x, y
Close #TransferExport

Next
MsgBox "Your file has been exported"

End Sub
```

^This is my first code. Please note that I am aware that for my "If-Then" selections of u, x, and y, I am selecting the entire column which is of course not what I want, but I cannot find a way to make it select only the corresponding row. While it does run, it cannot run completely as there are too many rows (18288) and the rows that it does manage to pull out simply all say "0", nor does it pull out the top row in each column as I specified in the data strings (the top row is the column names). I tried to do like this;

```
Dim rw As Range
Set rw = Sheets("Base").Range("F:F")
For i = 2 To 18288

If rw = "89" Then
u = Sheets("Base").Cells(rw, 1).Value
```

But this wont work. The other problem with this code is, that it won't overwrite the file if it already exists and instead just refuses to run.

The second code that I've tried is;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim data As String

Set rng = Range("F2:F18288")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "89" Then
        Sheets("Base").Cells(cell, "A").Select
        Sheets("Base").Cells(cell, "H").Select
        Sheets("Base").Cells(cell, "I").Select
        End If

 Selection.Copy
 data = "C:\Users\bruger1\Documents\Uni\TransferExport.csv"
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=data, _
FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next
MsgBox "Your file has been exported"

End Sub
```

I have several problems with this one; first, when I click the command button it will do different things for everytime I click? Sometimes it will continuously ask me if I want to overwrite the existing file, and also open a new document. Everytime I click yes it opens a new document and immediately asks me the same thing. If I click no or cancel it gives me a run-time error "1004". Sometimes it will export the file but also open a new workbook with a random value from my table which I did not try to pull out? Meanwhile the actual exported file "TransferExport" simply has single number "1" written in cell A1.

As said, I have been trying back and forth with any help I could find on the internet but nothing has worked so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this an [mcve]? Or is there a way you can whittle down your post to the relevant pieces?  Is this one issue, two, three+?

Comment: @BruceWayne I am aware this is quite a mouthful sorry about that. I am having 2 issues; selecting the values that I want and getting the exported file to overwrite. However I keep running into problems on the way which is why my question is so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()

    'Declare variables
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim sCSVPath As String
    Dim sCSVName As String
    Dim sSearchCol As String
    Dim vCriteria As Variant

    'Turn off these items to run code faster, prevent "screen flickering", and ignore warnings (such as if you want to override an existing file)
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'Set variables
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Base")                                  'This is the sheet containing the original data
    Set wsTemp = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    sCSVPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\Uni\"           'This is the folder path where the CSV file will be stored (automatically gets logged in user's username)
    sCSVName = "TransferExport.csv"                                 'Name of the CSV file
    sSearchCol = "F"                                                'Column in the original data to search
    vCriteria = 89                                                  'Critiera to search for in the specified column

    'Work with the specified column
    With wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(1, sSearchCol), wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, sSearchCol).End(xlUp))
        'Filter for the specified criteria
        .AutoFilter 1, vCriteria

        'Copy relevant columns (A, H, and I) to the temp worksheet as values only
        Intersect(.EntireRow, .Parent.Range("A:A,H:I")).Copy
        wsTemp.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'Remove the filter
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    'Move the temp sheet to its own workbook and save it as a CSV file and close it
    'Because we turned off item DisplayAlerts, this will automatically overwrite the file if it already exists
    wsTemp.Move
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sCSVPath & sCSVName, xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    'Turn items back on
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. This works so far but I have 2 small issues; It only copied the top row (the column names), so I tried to run it with  `wsTemp.Range("A:A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` instead, which gives me all the wanted rows, but they are repeated over and over for God knows how many rows. The second thing is, my excel uses semicolons as a "cell-seperator" and the results show up in 1 cell with commas. Is there a way to format this code to fit semicolons instead? Im quite new to vba so I don't know much.

Comment: @poetryemo If it's not copying anything over, then it didn't find anything matching the criteria in the Search Column.  If column F contains strings instead of numbers, set vCriteria to be `"89"` instead of just `89`.  I ran this code on a test workbook so I know it works.  As for the semicolons, that's not really a thing, even with different regional versions.  Once the cells are populated, saving it as a csv will make it a comma separated file as asked for.

Comment: I figured out how to solve the problem with the rows! 'wsTemp.Range("A1:A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` did the trick. Now I just need to figure out how to fix the comma/semicolon thing.

Comment: Alright so the semicolon/comma issue is because of my laptop settings and not my excel, so there's not much to do about that. Your code worked wonderfully though and thank you for putting the comments in as well, as it helped me understand the code, which is fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, please read the comments and try to understand everything happening in the code, feel free to ask questions:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim data As String, lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    'New Workbook
    Workbooks.Add
    Set awk = ActiveWorkbook
    'Copy all data to new Workbook
    wk.Sheets("Base").Columns("A:F").Copy
    awk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Find the lastRow in this data based on Column F (6)
    lastRow = awk.Worksheets(1).Cells(Excel.Rows.Count, 6).End(Excel.xlUp).Row
    'Loop and Remove any Row where F is NOT "89"
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If awk.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value <> "89" Then
            awk.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 6).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
    'Delete columns we dont want
    awk.Worksheets(1).Columns("B:G").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    'Save/Ovewrite It, Close it.
    data = "C:\Users\bruger1\Documents\Uni\TransferExport.csv"
    awk.SaveAs Filename:=data, FileFormat:=xlCSV, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, _
        ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    awk.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Your file has been exported"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! This takes a while for my laptop to load but it does work!

Comment: Please review changes in the code, it should be fast now.